# Ubuntu 20.04, Usb ports stop won't mount external drives

Tags: usb

Hi for some reason since upgrading to 20.04 my usb ports behave funny.

Any external drive that stays connected works fine.

However any drive un-mounted still leaves the drive listed in Files and any attempt at a later time to connect another drive does not detect the new new drive.

Only way to for the system to recognise the the new drive is to reboot or recently I found that suspending the system and waking it up then 'wakes' up the port again.

I have had my auto suspend disabled in my grub for a few ubuntu versions.

cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend

-1

UPDATE: the responses has been great. Useing the safely remove options correctly removes the drive from the files app now, But I still notice I have to suspend the laptop to wake up the USB port again. Even when using the exact same drive I just safely removed.

1 more thing I forgot to mention the usb ports are on a usb hub.

Thanks

Comment: Is it a **powered** USB hub?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for my devices.
You can once use this:

`udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdX`

And the next time, I should be alright and you would also have Safety Remove option.

Comment: Thank! both solutions presented seem to work from keeping the files app from showing a drive disconnected. But as an example after safely removing then plugging back in a minute later the same drive does not automount. Same thing forcing a suspend through power, and waking the laptop up a few seconds later then magically remounts the drives.

Ps I just noticed if you right click the drive in files app itself then use safely remove instead of clicking the eject button the drive does diseapper from the files app

Answer (score 0):

After ejecting the drive in `Files`, go to the `Disks` application and select the **Power Off** menu item. Then the drive can safely be removed from the USB port.

[image]

Comment: Thank! both solutions presented seem to work from keeping the files app from showing a drive disconnected. But as an example after safely removing then plugging back in a minute later the same drive does not automount. Same thing forcing a suspend through power, and waking the laptop up a few seconds later then magically remounts the drives.

Ps I just noticed if you right click the drive in files app itself then use safely remove instead of clicking the eject button the drive does diseapper from the files app